# Move UIView if keyboard is blocking a textview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Hello I have a UIView which is being displayed as a modal. The view contains some UITextView fields. The problem is when I edit some of the lower views, the keyboard pops up over the field hiding it.

I need a way to either make the view contents scrollable, or move the view contents up if the keyboard is blocking it. The view is created programmatically. I tried moving the view, but I am not able to get the active textview (the textViewDidBeginEditing method is never called). Here is my code..

**EditController.m**

```
- (void)editNavPressedEdit:(MapElement *)mapElement {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        EditAnnotationController *annotationController = [[EditAnnotationController alloc] init];
        annotationController.mapElement = mapElement;
        annotationController.delegate = self;

        UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:annotationController];
        navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        navigationController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(500, 500);
        navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
        navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

**EditDetailController.h**

```
@class MapElement;

@protocol EditAnnotationDelegate

- (void)editAnnotationSaved:(MapElement *)element;

- (void)editAnnotationCancelled;

@end

@interface EditAnnotationController : UIViewController <NavigationPickerDelegate, EditOverlayDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>

@property(nonatomic, strong) MapElement *mapElement;
@property(nonatomic, weak) id <EditAnnotationDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

**EditDetailController.m**

```
@implementation EditAnnotationController {
    UIView *_detailView;

    NSLayoutConstraint *_detailWidth;
    NSArray *_detailHoriz;

    NSMutableDictionary *_bindings;
    NSMutableArray *_detailObjects;

    NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter;

    UIButton *_dateButton;

    UISegmentedControl *_segmentedControl;
    NSArray *_segments;
    NSString *_segmentsBinding;

    UITextField *_radiusField;
    UITextView *_activeField;
}

@synthesize mapElement = _mapElement;
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _detailObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
    _bindings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    _dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    _dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";

    [self setUpDetailView];

    if (_mapElement) {
        [self setUpMapElement];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(save)];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)setUpDetailView {
    _detailView = [UIView new];
    _detailView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _detailView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:_detailView];

    NSArray *vertical = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view": _detailView}];
    _detailHoriz = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view": _detailView}];

    [self.view addConstraints:vertical];
    [self.view addConstraints:_detailHoriz];
}


- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {

    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        CGRect f = self.view.frame;
        f.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height + 250;
        self.view.frame = f;
    }];
}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    _activeField = textView;
}

- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    _activeField = nil;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        CGRect f = self.view.frame;
        f.origin.y = 44;
        self.view.frame = f;
    }];
}


- (void)setUpMapElement {
    [self setViewWidth:320];

    [self addImage:_mapElement.iconImage size:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];

    switch ([_mapElement.layerID intValue]) {
        case 1:
            [self configureHydrant];
            break;
    }

    [self addConstraints];
}


- (void)configureHydrant {
    [self addTitleLabel:@"Hydrant"];

    [self addHeaderLabel:@"Name:"];
    _bindings[propertyKeyPathLastComponent(_mapElement.subType)] = [self addTextField:_mapElement.subType];

    [self addHeaderLabel:@"Cap Color:"];

    _segments = @[@"Red", @"Blue", @"Green", @"Orange"];
    _segmentsBinding = propertyKeyPathLastComponent(_mapElement.steamerCapColor);
    [self addSegments:_segments selected:_mapElement.steamerCapColor];

    [self addHeaderLabel:@"Water line size:"];
    _bindings[propertyKeyPathLastComponent(_mapElement.waterLineSize)] = [self addTextField:_mapElement.waterLineSize.stringValue];

    [self addHeaderLabel:@"Flow rate:"];
    _bindings[propertyKeyPathLastComponent(_mapElement.flowRate)] = [self addTextField:_mapElement.flowRate.stringValue];

    [self addHeaderLabel:@"PSI:"];
    _bindings[propertyKeyPathLastComponent(_mapElement.psi)] = [self addTextField:_mapElement.psi.stringValue];

    [self addHeaderLabel:@"Notes:"];
    _bindings[propertyKeyPathLastComponent(_mapElement.description)] = [self addTextView:_mapElement.description];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you create the pertinent TextViews, set your ViewController as their delegate:

```
UITextField *myTextField = [UITextField alloc] init];
myTextField.delegate = self;
```

After this textViewDidBeginEditing should be called as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First register for 'UIKeyboardWillShowNotification' and 'UIKeyboardWillHideNotification' notification like following,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                                           selector:@selector(keyboardWillShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil]
```

then implement methods, 'keyboardWillShown:' and 'keyboardWillBeHidden:' like following,

```
- (void)keyboardWillShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

 if(selectedTextField.origin.y > self.view.size - kbSize.height){
     //shift view upwards
   }
 }

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
       //set origin of view to (0,0)
 }
```

Comment: My problem is that I'm not able to trigger the textViewDidBeginEditing method. I'm not able to get the active textview maybe because it's created programatically? @nikBhosale